# How to specify examples for GET parameters in Swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor, openapi

I'm using the online [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io) to create a Swagger spec for my API.

My API has a single GET request endpoint, and I'm using the following YAML code to describe the input parameters:

```
paths:
  /fooBar:
    get:
      tags:
        - foobar
      summary: ''
      description: ''
      operationId: foobar
      consumes:
        - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: address
          in: query
          description: Address to be foobared
          required: true
          type: string
          example: 123, FakeStreet
        - name: city
          in: query
          description: City of the Address
          required: true
          type: string
          example: New York
```

If I put in the `example` tag, I get an error saying:

> is not exactly one from <#/definitions/parameter>,<#/definitions/jsonReference>

How do I set an example when writing GET parameters in Swagger?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### OpenAPI 2.0

OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 does not have the `example` keyword for non-body parameters. You can specify examples in the parameter `description`. Some tools like Swagger UI v2, v3.12+ and Dredd also support the `x-example` extension property for this purpose:

```yaml
      parameters:
        - name: address
          in: query
          description: Address to be foobared. Example: `123, FakeStreet`.  # <-----
          required: true
          type: string
          x-example: 123, FakeStreet   # <-----
```

#### OpenAPI 3.x

Parameter examples are supported in OpenAPI 3.x:

```yaml
      parameters:
        - name: address
          in: query
          description: Address to be foobared
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            example: 123, FakeStreet   # <----
          example: 456, AnotherStreet  # Overrides the schema-level example
```