# How to provide sample request for "get" method in openapi/swagger?

Tags: swagger, openapi

For post and put methods, this can be done using requestBody, but i have filters and want to add some examples.

```
{{url}}/api/method?filter[qweqwe]=Test
```

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [How to specify examples for GET parameters in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43933516/113116)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify examples for GET parameters in Swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933516/how-to-specify-examples-for-get-parameters-in-swagger)